# Jordan form, rearrangement of Jordan blocks, conjugate but not similar

Tags: matrices, jordan-normal-form

$$A_1=\begin{bmatrix}\lambda&1&\\&\lambda\\&&\lambda\end{bmatrix}$$
$$A_2=\begin{bmatrix}\lambda&&\\&\lambda&1\\&&\lambda\end{bmatrix}$$

These are conjugate but not similar apparently. What the?

I thought the very notion of similarity was based on being conjugate?

I.e. A_1=P^{-1}A_2P$ means that they are similar and means they are conjugate. Why are these Jordan forms apparently conjugate but not similar?

Comment: Can you show us the reference where they say that they are conjugate but not similar ?

Answer (score 1):

$A_1$ and $A_2$ are conjugate under the change of basis matrix $S = \left[ \begin{array}{ccc} 0 & 0 & 1\\ 1 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 1 & 0\end{array}\right]$. This, by definition, means that they are similar. You're right that conjugate and similar are synonyms in this context.